# Shutdown Clickonce application

Tags: clickonce, shutdown

I am new to clickonce application. From a global application we have buttons to launch other windows/usercontrols (*.exe, clickone, xbaps, etc.). When the global application shutsdown it is supposed to close all applications it has launched. For any other .exe or xbap, we always have a handle to close them but for click once we are facing some problems.

ClickOnce applications launched from our global app always have Window.

**Question**

1. When user click "X" on a ClickOnce app Window does this uninstall clickonce or shuts it down?
2. How to shut down a clickonce app from another application (in my case from the global app which launched clickonce in first place?)

Please note that I do not want to uninstall clickonce, I just want to close the clickonce app.

Thanks,

RDV

Answer (score 0):

1. It shuts the app down. ClickOnce runs every time it is started and downloaded every time the manifest changes.
2. To shutdown the application from your global app call a method on your clickonce application to issue
   `System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();`

Comment: That is my problem, I do not have handle to my click once app.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that ClickOnce apps have names and taskmanager shows the application name as "myclickonceapp.exe". Getting handle of this app, my global app could close the clickonce application.

Thanks,

RDV